# Is there a way to wait until a window is hidden, rather than closed like ShowDialog() does?

Tags: c#, wpf

Put very simply,

```
new myForm().ShowDialog()
```

waits until the dialog is closed before continuing execution, and I would like this behavior, except that it should wait for the dialog to be *hidden* before continuing.

Comment: Instead of reading the properties of the form why not use `myForm.DataContext = myViewModel` and set that before you call `ShowDialog()` then you could just read the values from `myViewModel` and not worry about stuff being disposed.

Comment: Note for the original question that Show(), plus something that waits for it to be hidden, is fine, but I didn't find an event that I could subscribe to along those lines (may just be an oversight in the WPF framework, would not surprise me).

Answer (score 1):

You could handle the `IsVisibleChanged` event and use a `await` a `TaskCompletionSource<T>` to block asynchronously until the event is raised, e.g.:

```
private async void OpenDialog_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TaskCompletionSource<bool> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    var window = new DialogWindow();
    window.IsVisibleChanged += (ss, ee) =>
    {
        if (!window.IsVisible)
            tcs.SetResult(true);
    };
    window.Show();
    this.IsEnabled = false;
    await tcs.Task;

    MessageBox.Show("window hidden!");
}
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it spreads the async virus, while the original method does not. Now, I know Microsoft says to just [let the zombie virus spread](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx), but there are clearly problems with that approach to life. More importantly, an async version isn't an equivalent method to the ShowDialog() method.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a hack really, but you could bind the visibility of the control to a property in the datacontext of the view (just after initializing it), and do your logic there. Alternatively if it's your code that's throwing the exception could you not just check for null?